# Strange number at the end of wordpress permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I've just noticed in my google webmaster tools that there are 404 errors and they are pointing from my permalinks which have this number in the end : 9223372036854775807.

For example this url :

> http://www.designzzz.com/beautiful-pictures-nature/

is shown as this

> http://www.designzzz.com/beautiful-pictures-nature/9223372036854775807/

and works fine.

I got worried that there might be some hacking or other issue in my site and google it. I found that many urls from different wordpress sites are indexed with this same number in the end. So I am curious what is this about.

[Google QUery](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3aDesignzzz.com%209223372036854775807/101092815765978131399&oq=site%3aDesignzzz.com%209223372036854775807/101092815765978131399&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=9223372036854775807%20in%20wordpress&safe=off)

Comment: Does this stop if you disable all of your plugins?

Comment: i updated my w3 total cahche and wp seo it isn't showing these numbers anymore as 404s in my google webmaster tools, but the problem still persists in a way that if you run the above url with numbers it works. it shud redirect to original url i guess

Comment: I had the same problem, and I found an answer here : http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-infinite-duplicate-content/ Hope it s help !